# Android application to share " Wi-Fi connection over Wi-Fi"

Tags: android, wifi

I am looking for android application to tether Wi-Fi over WiFi, which has a similar functionality to "Share Wi-Fi profile" feature in premium Samsung devices.

[image: screenshot]

I tried and tested this functionality and it really does share wifi connection to other devices.

**Please note I am not talking about normal tethering of 3g/4g connection,  thus I kindly ask not recommend such softwares.**

As for the usefulness of such functionality, an example use case: I have a Symbian device (among other devices) which doesn't connect to captive portals Wi-Fi logins. So using described functionality, I could connect to the captive portal using my Android device, and provide a "non-captive" WiFi to that Symbian device.

I have been looking for such for a long time, and unfortunately some fake apps claimed to do this but never achieved this. So the quest continues

Comment: Forgive me but what would be the purpose of this?

Comment: @LiamWiliam.  Its okay, I have a Symbian device (among other devices) which doesn't connect to captive portals Wi-Fi logins,  and I subscribe to a such  Wi-Fi service , so I wanted all my devices to have internet connection hence I need this feature to get access to Wifi via Android possibly since its the only option

Comment: My guess is that you would need to wifi cards to something like this which is why there are no apps supporting this.  But you have probably done my research then me.

Comment: "which has a similar functionality to "Share Wi-Fi profile" feature in premium Samsung devices." And those are? :) Remember that asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. The basics are clear, but the specials are not – or is "sharing WiFi over WiFi" the only functionality?

Comment: @Izzy I am not sure about the specifics, and I have asked a question already on another Stack exchange network asking for [actual specific functionality](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/173875/209414) and has not received any response yet, but once I get one, I promise to edit this question stating the specific functionality. Right now all I know is "WiFi tethering through WiFi"

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I vaguely remember we had something similar at Android.SE with an answer. It's even (indirectly) linked from the "Related" section of your question (with a duplicate in between): [Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12616/16575) (via [Can I use an existing Wifi Network as source for internet connectivity and still enable WiFi tethering?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14278/16575)) Unfortunately, link in the accepted answer is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the application capable of doing this

[NetShare tethering (no root) application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&hl=en) is  a solution to the problem addresed.

- Apart from other "extra" features it offers, I was only interesting in this *WLAN direct via proxy concept*.

> Now this application uses a vpn proxy to route traffic from device
>   connected to Wi-Fi network to another client via a p2p connectivity.

- Essentially, it uses a HTTP proxy to route traffic to the client and configuring the connection is fairly easy:

  1. Go to connection settings of any device e.g PC, Iphone etc (but in this case used a Symbian device)
  2. Add the wireless acess point if not done already, and input the Wi-Fi direct Group password.
  3. Under advanced settings change proxy settings:

  `Server: 192.168.49.1`

  `Port: 8282`

  (remember to allow this port on firewall settings for other devices)

[image]